# Angular 2: Where is url 'api/heroes' defined?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I was going through part 7 of [Angular 2 Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) tutorial. After including InMemoryWebApiModule the `hero.service.ts` uses `private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';`.

How does the app know the WebAPI url is `api/heroes`? I don't see this defined in `app-routing.module.ts`. How does the url mapping to InMemoryWebApiModule work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going on my experience here ... not in depth knowledge of the InMemoryWebApiModule...

It appears that the "api" is captured by the InMemoryWebApi. And the "heroes" is the data structure defined in the createDb() method.

For example, mine looks like this:

```
private baseUrl = 'api/products';
```

And my data file looks like this:

```
export class ProductData implements InMemoryDbService, InMemoryBackendConfig {
    createDb() {
        let products: IProduct[] = [ ...];
        return { products };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right near the top of the page,of that tutorial they define the import for this.

--Removed off-topic code reference, I kind of misread the question a bit.--

and then, below that they give us the code for said item.

The InMemoryWebAPI uses the 
https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api
to create a local database, that calls to it will reference. This module seems to be the item that is capturing/registering the /api calls.

This is just an alternative to using an actual backend.

Answer (score 1):

InMemoryWebApi is an opinionated tool - it uses its internal conventions.

The `createDb` method is supposed to return an object where the key (ie. where you attach your data) will match the slug of your api URL, so in order to handle the slug of `heroes`, return `{ heroes: yourData }`. Typically, a shorthand is used in cases like this one:

```
const heroes = [ /* your data */ ];
return { heroes };
```

Now, `api` is a default prefix this library assumes. It can be changed to match your specific case, just provide it as part of the `InMemoryBackendConfigArgs` argument. For example, if you know your endpoint for heroes will be located at `myapi/v2/heroes`, use the following config:

```
HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(DataInmemService, {
  apiBase: 'myapi/v2'
})
```

Comment: Tweaking apiBase parameter solved my issue, after I spent 4 hours trying to understand why I cant get fake data.